# Change mutliple Directory keys at once in python

Tags: python

I have feeling that if I knew what to search for, I would find the answer. But....

I have a large 2D array ([83][1000]) of dictionaries. Each dictionary has 6 keys that are all initialized to False when I build the array. I then need to go through the array and set various Keys to True based on where that particular point is in the array. I need to set several keys to True. I can do them one at a time but that just does not seem correct.

```
>>> EvenArray[0]
{'Pierce': False, 'Include': False, 'Deboss': False, 'Button': False, 'Exclude': False, 'Emboss': False}
```

I would like to set `"Pierce"`, `"Button"` both `True`, i.e.:

```
EvenArray[0]["Pierce","Button"]=True,True
```

But I get:

```
>>> EvenArray[0]
{'Pierce': True, 'Include': False, 'Deboss': False, 'Button': True, ('Pierce', 'Button'): (True, True), 'Exclude': False, 'Emboss': False}
```

So what I am doing:

```
>>> EvenArray[0]["Button"]=True;EvenArray[0]["Pierce"]=True
>>> EvenArray[0]
{'Pierce': True, 'Emboss': False, 'Deboss': False, 'Button': True, 'Exclude': False, 'Include': False}
>>>
```

I am new to python but that just does not look pythonic...

There are a great number of different combinations of Key values based on position in the array. But you get the idea. (I still need all the other key:values)

Comment: Rather than dictionaries with Boolean values, you might want to try using sets. An empty set would be equivalent to a dictionary with all `False` values, and one with a few items would be equivalent to the dictionary with just those keys having `True` values. You could then do your updates with the `update` method, or with the `|=` operator.

Comment: Yep as suspected. Now I know to search for .update and I immediately found what I needed. Thanks. I am moving forward with the Dict. plan. But as time permits I will come back to the set approach. The array contains 86,000 elements. It will interesting to see which approach it faster in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just a few keys to update, use [`update()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) with keyword arguments, like this:

```
EventArray[0].update(Button=True, Pierce=True)
```

Otherwise, you can pass the whole dictionary:

```
new_data = {'Button': True, 'Pierce': True, ... }
EventArray[0].update(new_data)
```